# Safari sub domain cookie issue

Tags: tomcat, cookies, safari

I have 2 sub domains that need to be part of a process, an elegant dance if you will.

foo.domain.com
This one will create a cookie with domain set to ".domain.com" and path set to "/"

bar.domain.com
This one needs to read the cookie created above.

This is working fine with Chrome, but Safari isn't passing the cookie to bar.domain.com

I'm using a Tomcat server if that makes a difference.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious because I couldn't find anyone have this exact issue online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a bad build of Safari. Everything worked out just fine.